# On composition of functions

Tags: functions

Supose the following functions:

$f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$, $g(x)=\frac{1}{x+1}$, $(f\circ g)(x)$ and $h(x)=x+1$.

Am I right in saying that $(f\circ g)(x)\neq h(x)$? I believe that this is so because while the domain of $(f\circ g)(x)$ is $\mathbb{R}-\left\{ -1\right\}{}$, the domain of $h(x)$ is $\mathbb{R}$, but for every functions $i,j$, if $i(x)=j(x)$, then $dom(i)=dom(j)$.

I am quite disturbed by the fact that GeoGebra draws the function $f(g(x))$ as it were the function $h(x)$.

Thank you.

Comment: $f(x) \circ g(x) $ is wrong notation -- it should be $f\circ g$ if you're talking about the _function_ and $(f\circ g) (x) $ for its value at a particular point.

Answer (score 1):

$f \circ g$ is equal to $h$ on some subsets of $\mathbb R$, so they are equal and they are not, depending on your choice of domain ($\mathbb R$ is the maximal possible domain and they are not equal on all of $\mathbb R$, right as you say, because of undefinability).

But even this can be fixed because of $g(-1)=+ \infty$ and $g(-1)=- \infty $ and $f(g(-1)))= \frac {1}{+ \infty}=0$ and $f(g(-1)))= \frac {1}{-\infty}=0$ and $h(-1)=-1+1=0$

$g$ is "multivalued" at $-1$ and has two values, $+ \infty$ and $- \infty$, if you like it like this.

Comment: I'd rather have it fixed by removing $-1$ from the domain for all those functions, rather than by adding two new elements $+\infty$ and $-\infty$ - *way* too many people think infinities are numbers that they can calculate with.